# slate like theme for emacs?

Tags: emacs

Is there any themes for emacs which looks like this one?
http://www.lnbogen.com/VisualStudioNet2005Colors.aspx

Comment: looks somewhat similar to Gray30 theme in the color theme package (by Girish Bharadwaj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be worth having a look at package `color-theme`, although I can't see anything that matches precisely what you want on the sample page.

See [here](http://code.google.com/p/gnuemacscolorthemetest/) for screenshots (links at the bottom of the page), and [here](http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme/) for the code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a variation of the zenburn theme, which is also available for [emacs](http://brockman.se/2003/zenburn/).

Answer (score 0):

It easy to make your own color theme, for instance you can see in my [init.el](http://pablo.rauzy.name/init.el.html) file (search for `global-font-lock-mode` to get to the interresting part) how easily it can be done.